# friend of a class doesn't access private values of a class in CPP

Tags: c++, oop, friend

I want to ask a question about friends of a class in C++.

I am a beginner in C++ and learning about overloading operators as global functions.

I wrote the following part of a class declaration in the `Mystrings.h` file and the corresponding function in the `Mystrings.cpp` file.

for `Mystrings.h` :

```
class Mystring
{
    friend bool operator==(const Mystring &lhs, const Mystring &rhs);
    friend Mystring operator-(const Mystring &obj);
    friend Mystring operator+(const Mystring &lhs, const Mystring &rhs);
private:
    char *str; // pointer to a char[] that holds a c-style string
```

and for `Mystrings.cpp`:

```
Mystring operator-(Mystring &obj) {
char *buff = new char[std::strlen(obj.str)+1];
std::strcpy(buff, obj.str);
for (size_t i = 0; i < std::strlen(buff); i++)
    buff[i] = std::tolower(buff[i]);
Mystring temp {buff};
delete [] buff;
return temp;
}

// concatenation
Mystring operator+(const Mystring &lhs, const Mystring &rhs) {
    char *buff = new char [std::strlen(lhs.str) + std::strlen(rhs.str) + 1];
    std::strcpy(buff, lhs.str);
    std::strcat(buff, rhs.str);
    Mystring temp {buff};
    delete [] buff;
    return temp;
}
```

For my main CPP file I was trying to make the following work:

```
Mystring three_stooges = moe + " " + larry + " " + "Curly";
three_stooges.display(); // Moe Larry Curly
```

However, the compiler returns an error:

```
error: 'str' is a private member of 'Mystring'
```

for the lines

```
char *buff = new char[std::strlen(obj.str)+1];
std::strcpy(buff, obj.str);
```

I can't seem to see why.

I know that as I am declaring the friends of the function, they are now able to access the private string pointer, `*str` yet the error still persists. The concatenation operator `+` functions as normal but I can't work out why the error above persists.

Why is this error being yielded?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The friend has a `const`, did you notice? `Mystring operator-(Mystring &obj)` lacks it.

Comment: Signature difference `friend Mystring operator-(const Mystring &obj);`  vs `Mystring operator-(Mystring &obj)`

Comment: The hacker deep in me loves that you are allocating and freeing memory based on strlen() , then using strcpy()  - but that is a much more advanced lesson :)

Comment: @RichardCritten out of interest, how does the omission of `const` result in the fact that it can't access `str` in the first place?

Comment: `Mystring` could probably benefit from having and using a `size` member to track the length of the stored string.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan it was covered in my course I genuinely had no idea it was an advanced topic until I saw it discussed here on SO but glad to know my course set me up nicely!

Comment: If the function signatures don't match, they are not the same function. Effectively `Mystring` is Bob's friend, not Alice's.

Comment: @bodn19888 `Mystring operator-(Mystring &obj)` is not a member function or a friend function - it's just a top level function with no special access rights.

Comment: @RichardCritten of course - it has no relation to the friend function prototype I defined in the class! Understood clearly!

Answer (score 1):

Simple error:

The function prototype for unary minus `operator-` contains a `const` but this was omitted in the `Mystrings.cpp` file.

Comment: The problem isn't in the concatenation (`operator+`), but in the unary minus (`operator-`). Although the posted code doesn't use that operator, its definition is where the error is being reported. It's the only code that refers to `obj.str`. If you clarify that, you've got a good answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker Done!